# Do I have to use 'DesktopBuild' target when using TFSBuild to execute MSBuild Scripts?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, continuous-integration, tfsbuild

I would like to create an msbuild script that just promotes an application from my CI server to production (copies from A to B). So I don't want or need the TFSBuild.proj to build a solution. There is no solution for it to build in this case.

How can I do this? Can I just change the project "DefaultTargets" to point to custom targets that I define within my TfsBuild.proj? So can I just change the below?

```
    <Project DefaultTargets="DesktopBuild" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="3.5">

  <!-- Do not edit this -->
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets" />
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question fortunately. You can override basically everything in Desktop build beneath the Import of "\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.target"

See this [Post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/ea95d01b-4fe2-4e16-af26-e91b7ea90e81) if you are having this problem!